# Any Static Code Analysis Tools for Stored Procedures?

Tags: database, t-sql, stored-procedures, plsql, static-analysis

Are there any [static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis) tools for [stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) written particularly in [PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL_SQL) and [T-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL)?

Comment: There is a free tool call Manduka (http://manduka.tech) which supports both PL/SQL and T-SQL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For T-SQL, Microsoft has the database edition of VS Team Suite (although, I believe its now in the dev SKU). This link talks about writing your own static code analysis rule for T-SQL:  http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2009/01/01/creating-t-sql-static-code-analysis-rules.aspx

Comment: Related reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172133.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193244.aspx

Comment: I would accept this answer as well. Its just that becuase my question has two parts (one for PLSQL and other for TSQL) there are two separate answers but stackoverflow allows only one to be accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Oracle has some little-known stuff built in.

Try this in 10g Release 2 or above:

```
ALTER SESSION PLSQL_WARNINGS = 'ENABLE:ALL';
```

Then compile your PL/SQL package (not an anonymous block).

Answer (score 4):

Toad features the [CodeXpert](http://www.toadsoft.com/get2know9/#Xpert) utility to statically check your PL/SQL code.

The utility can either scan files or connect directly to the Oracle database.  As far as I've seen, works only on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Try free [Sql Code Guard](http://sqlcodeguard.com/). It provides fast and comprehensive static analysis for T-Sql code, shows code complexity and objects dependencies

Answer (score 3):

For PL/SQL, Toad CodeXpert can be [extended with Sonar](http://www.toadworld.com/BLOGS/tabid/67/EntryID/400/Default.aspx), an open source tool to manage code quality through a plugin.

I guess it would be possible to write a plugin for T-SQL as well.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest thing that I know of are the [estimated and actual query plan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx) functions available in [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) but I'd guess there's [similar](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) for [other](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_execution_plan_tips.htm) SQL engines.

Answer (score 2):

Our [SD Source Code Search Engine](http://www.sematnicdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine) is a tool for interactively searching large source code bases in many computer languages (including PL/SQL) efficiently, by preindexing the source code files by their tokens (identifiers, numbers, etc).  As a side effect of the preindexing step, it computes standard metrics:  SLOC, Cyclomatic, Halstead, ... for each file and produces a report. See the site for an example.

Our [SD CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) is a tool for analyzing large code bases for redundant code.  We've applied it to PL/SQL, and have seen something like 45% of the code involved in clones. YMMV. The CloneDR works with a large variet of langauges; see the site for sample clone detection runs on some of those other langauges.

EDIT 10/4/2010:

Our [Source Code Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine) is designed to enable very fast searches across large codes of mixed languages.  It succeeds by preindexing the source code.  As a side effect of the indexing step, it compute a variety of metrics including Cyclomatic and Halstead measures of complexity.

Just added: not a static analysis tool, but one generally of interest to people interested software quality:
our [TestCoverage for PLSQL stored procedures](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/PLSQLTestCoverage.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. Regardng PL/SQL, since Oracle doesn't expose much of their PL/SQL compilation engine its hard to find tool support.

The most I've been able to do is to query the data dictionary to do things like map the package dependencies.

Comment: So one has to have another engine that can handle PL/SQL.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/LanguageTools/PLSQLTools.html

Answer (score 0):

As a followup on the post for T-SQL; VS2010 and VS2008 database development editions come with build-in static analysis rules.  These are user extensible, i.e. you can write your own analysis rules in a .net language.  The open-source project Neznayka comes with an initial set of 22 rules, and forms a useful base for you to start contributing your own.

Admittedly you have to fork out for Visual Studio and be prepared to develop db code using
VS projects, but the recent releases of SSDT as a plug-in for SSMS raises the prospect that Microsoft may, if it has the will-power to do so, allow user-written rules to be distributed to environments that use MS SQL projects 'for free' to develop database code.

The link for [Neznayka](http://neznayka.codeplex.com/).

Or search the web.