# Are there any good tools for SQL Server database design static analysis?

Tags: sql-server, static-analysis, software-quality

I'm interested in the existence of any tools which can perform static analysis against a SQL Server database. In essence, I'm looking for the DB equivalent of FxCop or NDepend; something which can inspect the data layer and come back with recommendations around metrics such as design, naming and any other measurable attributes relating to quality.

Has anyone used a tool in the past that can provide some design feedback? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2010 ?? Using its database projects, you get a lot of code and design analysis tools (for free, if you already have VS)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176697/static-analysis-tools-for-database-design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use SQL 2008, or have an instance of SQL 2008 anywhere, you can use policy based management. This will do what you want. [Check Here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1492) This will work for naming and other standards, but might not work on data metrics.

You can alway use the Microsoft [Best Practices analyzer for SQL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsecurity/thread/49eeb04d-c435-4316-acf5-d552da8df7c5)

Answer (score 0):

DataCleaner http://datacleaner.eobjects.org/

Answer (score 0):

SQL Enlight is a dedicated static analysis tool for SQL Server, working in SSMS as well as part of Continuous Integration. There is [a review on Simple Talk by Grant Fritchey](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-enlight-for-sql-server-management-studio/). There are numerous built-in tests as well as a capability (albeit complicated looked) to author one's own checks.

[SQL Cop](http://sqlcop.lessthandot.com/) is another option. It's not as sophisticated as SQL Enlight, and can't be automated as part of a build process, but is free.