# Code Analysis in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, code-analysis

Do you know of any good (and if possible free) tool for SQL Server 2005/2008 development like there is Code Analysis and ReSharper for .NET development?

I know these are completely different programming styles (unfortunately, since I wish today's SQL syntax was like that of most modern language and not just a set of "extensions" on a poorly-designed, old syntax), but anyway some tools like those would definately come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought Visual Studio team edition for database professionals, "Data Dude", or whatever it is called these days had a static code analysis portion, and I am fairly certain the next version (Denali / Juneau) will as well. Of course this is not free. I don't know of any others off-hand, but for such a niche market I would suggest that either it is important to you or it isn't; if you try to focus just on free solutions, you may come up empty-handed or at least short-handed.

Comment: Also see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531430/any-static-code-analysis-tools-for-stored-procedures